# WSUS и новые ПК

Tags: windows, update, active-directory, group-policy, wsus

При тестировании сервера WSUS в домене возникло два вопроса:
- почему новыe ПК всегда попадают в "Неназначенные" независимо от настроек WSUS-a Параметры/Компьютеры?
- почему некоторые ПК получают обновления в то время как нет никаких Утверждений и Автоутверждение отключено для всех?